# I have this permutation "/^(?:([A-L])(?!.*\1)){12}$/g" but I want to divide it whith "," a comma, How can I make it

Tags: javascript, regex, permutation

Could somebody tell me how I can make a permutation divided with comma?

I have this regular expression: `/^(?:([A-L])(?!.*\1)){12}$/g`.

This permutation finds a line that have `[A-L]` characters without repetitions

For example,

```js
var regex = /^(?:([A-L])(?!.*\1)){12}$/g;
"ABCDEFGHIJKL".match(regex); // [ "ABCDEFGHIJKL" ]
"IFAHBGEJKLCD".match(regex); // [ "IFAHBGEJKLCD" ]
```

But I want to get `A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L` or `I,F,A,H,B,G,E,J,K,L,C,D`.

Comment: exemple: ABCDEFGHIJKL   or IFAHBGEJKLCD.

I want this A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L   or I,F,A,H,B,G,E,J,K,L,C,D.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're looking for. Could you edit your question to include some example input and output?

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```js
var regex = /^(?:([A-L])(?!.*\1)){12}$/;
("ABCDEFGHIJKL".match(regex) || [''])[0].split('');
    // ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L"]
("IFAHBGEJKLCD".match(regex) || [''])[0].split('');
    // ["I","F","A","H","B","G","E","J","K","L","C","D"]
("------------".match(regex) || [''])[0].split('');
    // [  ]
```

Explanation:

- `str.match(regex)` will return an array containing the match, or `null` if there is no match.
- If there is a match, I get it using `[0]`, and then I `split` it into an an array of characters.
- If there is no match, I use `['']` to avoid errors.

Once you have the array, you can use `join()` if you want:

```
var regex = /^(?:([A-L])(?!.*\1)){12}$/;
("ABCDEFGHIJKL".match(regex) || [''])[0].split('').join();
    // "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L"
("IFAHBGEJKLCD".match(regex) || [''])[0].split('').join();
    // "I,F,A,H,B,G,E,J,K,L,C,D"
("------------".match(regex) || [''])[0].split('').join();
    // ""
```